# TFS2010 workflow activity "InvokeProcess": How to display the process on the agent instead of running it in background?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-automation

I have created a BuildProcessTemplate that invokes a custom compiler. This compiler is normally running inside a command shell. It spawns lots of other processes running in a command shell in order to compile the code in parallel.

Now we are migrating to TFS and would like to trigger the build process from TFS. This works fine using the "InvokeProcess" activity. However, when the InvokeProcess activity is started, the command shells are not shown on the agent computer. They are running in the background. We would like them to be displayed.

Is it possible to somehow tell the InvokeProcess that it should interactively start the process?

Thanks for your help,

Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution...

The Build service on the agent machine needs to be run as an interactive process, not as a service. This can be configured from the TFS Administration Console:

[image]

Just tick the "Interactive Process" radio button.
(On this Image both TFS application tier and Build service is on the same machine, which should not be done by the way!)